# Bluetooth chat sample

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have the most stupidest question to ask, but its really flipping me out.

I want to download the project for the Bluetooth chat sample, but when I see this link: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html  it just defaults to this link: http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html . I assume the link to the sample code must have been taken down, Can anyone pls provide me with the project in zip file? It would really help me a lot thanks.

Comment: You can create a project from SDK samples.And from there you can compile this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to SDK level 17, the BluetoothChat sample can be found in your SDK, directory `samples/android-n/BluetoothChat` (where `n` is `17` or lower). If you only have newer SDK versions installed, install older ones with the SDK manager first.